# Enter and exit module environments?

Tags: ubuntu

I apologize for being a complete linux noob! Here is my question:

I am trying to use [OpenAI gym](https://gym.openai.com/docs/) in Ubuntu. After I first did the installation, my command line in the terminal went from looking like

```
user@localhost:~$
```

to

```
(gym) user@localhost:~$
```

and I could execute files such as

```
(gym) user@localhost:/mnt/e/MyOpenAIstuff$ python script.py
```

which require the gym module.

Now when I start the terminal again, it starts in the `user@localhost:~$` state and when I try to run a script it does not recognize the `gym` module by saying that `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym'`. I suspect that I need to issue some command to get the terminal back into the

```
(gym) user@localhost:~$
```

state before using gym in my scripts. What command should I use to enter such a module state?

PS:

So far I tried adding

```
export GYM_PATH="/home/user/gym/bin:$GYM_PATH"
```

to `.bashrc` and calling `source ~/.bashrc`, which unfortunately did not fix the issue.

Comment: I don't know `gym`, but you won't find it unless you give its full path (presumably `/home/user/gym/bin/gym`) or you add its location to `PATH` with `export GYM="/home/user/gym/bin:$PATH"`. Once it starts it may or may not use `GYM_PATH` to find scripts without directory paths: if it does, you need `export GYM_PATH="/home/user/gym/bin"`, assuming that there is no previous setting of `GYM_PATH` - you don't want a trailing `:`.

Comment: If they work, let me know, and I'll submit it as an answer, so that others can see that there is a solution.